# Can I make the data dump of a closed SE site public?

Tags: support, data-dump, closed-sites

Let’s say I download the data dump of a closed site. The SE site is not available any more and not every one can read the data dump easily. Am I allowed to display the data in readable form on a public site?

Comment: Which site doesn't have a data-dump? They all should have them, even closed sites, see [economics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics)

Comment: @BenBrocka made my question more clear, I think it was slightly bad worded. I have the data dump already.

Comment: Oh, I gotcha. I don't think the data dump is hard to read by design (meaning they don't want it easily readable) but rather that's just the easiest way to release all the data and they haven't made a viewer for that data yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's licensed CC BY SA irrevocably...so yes, you can always make data-dumps public given proper attribution, legally speaking (that's part of their intent). And data-dumps for closed sites should always be available via Area 51 anyway.

Comment: Yeah, if a data dump is missing from Area 51, it's probably just because we derped. I'm not sure what the process is/if we can always dig one up, but ping us if you find a closed site without a published data dump  and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: My problem is I want to read the contents of this close site and it is only available in dump so my point was I want to make it in readable form in public domain. Just wanted to clear this up :) I think I can make it public, from this answer?

Comment: @Dave Yes, you can do anything you want with the data dump, provided you follow the CC BY SA licence religiously. That means no "public domain", you need to be very specific with attribution.

Comment: How do you satisfy the linking requirements of CC-SA if the link destination is no longer there?  That is, I'm supposed to link to the original post/user/etc, but that'll be a 404 -- what do I do instead?