# Is it allowed to read the data dump of a closed SE site into a clone SE site model to start a new Q&A site?

Tags: support, data-dump, closed-sites

Is it allowed to read the data dump of a closed SE site into one of the Stack Exchange site models listed for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/184300) and use it as a base of questions to start a new Q&A site (or continue the closed one) outside the Stack Exchange network?

The first legal problem with this which comes to mind concerns the correct attribution of the content. In the licence.text file that is contained in the data dump it is explained that one has to

1. Visually indicate that the content is from our sites in some way. It
   doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site
   (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
3. Show the author names for every question and answer
4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page
   on the source site (e.g.,
   https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

To fulfill point 2. and point 4. [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65948/184300) answer says, that it is enough to refer to the closed Area51 proposal.

Are there other legal issues that have to be considered?

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141567/184300) question is related, but it's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141569/184300) does not fully answer my case, in particular Yannis comment confuses me.

Comment: Yannis just says you need to abide by the license, you cannot claim on your republish site that the content in Public Domain instead. You have the steps down pat, I'd say.

Comment: +1 It's good that you asked and took the time to do some basic research.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, there are many legal issues that have to be considered when hosting user-generated content. You might face challenges about specific content that is prohibited in some legislatures, including content relating to: the protection of minors; the protection of ownership of intellectual property; defamation; hate speech; and many other areas.

But that's not really relevant to this board.

The only two questions that are relevant to this board, have already been answered:

> To fullfil point 2. and point 4

Jeff Atwood has already answered that [a link the Area51 page is probably sufficient](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65948/164022).

> Is it allowed to read the data dump of a closed SE site into one of the Stack Exchange site models listed for example here and use it as a base of questions to start a new Q&A site (or continue the closed one) outside the Stack Exchange network?

[Yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141567/164022), as Ben Brocka has answered already.

---

*footnote 1:* Please also bear in mind that becoming a host of user-generated content will give you a whole new perspective on the philosophy and policies of moderation. Having one's strongly-held beliefs contradicted by the real world may cause discomfort.

*footnote 2:* meta.SO denizens bewildered by footnote 1, might seek enlightenment in meta.physics