# Is it allowed to use the content of a (not-closed) SE site to A new Q & A site based on an SE clone?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange, data-dump, policy

> **Related:**     [Is it allowed to read the data dump of a closed SE site into a clone SE site model to start a new Q&A site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195920/is-it-allowed-to-read-the-data-dump-of-a-closed-se-site-into-a-clone-se-site-mod?lq=1)

Similar to the related question, but what if the site is not closed? Example: Can    someone              use a small portion (filtered by tags) content of the existing site (note *existing*; not closed), such as Physics.SE, in another site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed.

So long as you follow the attribution requirements of the license, there is no problem.

The question you linked to and the question linked in the answer have all the details.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS - Beta and graduated sites are also in the data dump.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS - The data dumps on Area51 are for failed betas. The data dump for graduated and current beta sites has Physics and all others. The latest one can be found [here](http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/2155-sept-2013).

Comment: @Oded - Just related question: Is it allowed to post the same question from one proposal (closed) to another proposal (re-creation of that closed proposal)?

Comment: @hims056 - I am not entirely clear on area51 rules as some are, but I am sure that if you cite the source, this will be fine.